# 3D border decorator in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, decorator

I need to give a 3D effect of a WPF control that I will use in an other WPF Control.

```
<UserControl>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Border BorderThickness="0">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                                  ShadowDepth="3"
                                  Direction="270" />
            </Border.Effect>
            <my:MyChildWpfControl x:Name="myControl"/>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Is there a way to **directly** put `myControl` into the `ScrollViewer`, **without using Border child** node?
Something about *decorators* and *adorners*... What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean?

```
<UserControl>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <my:MyChildWpfControl>
            <my:MyChildWpfControl.BitmapEffect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                                  ShadowDepth="3"
                                  Direction="270" />
            </my:MyChildWpfControl.BitmapEffect>
        </my:MyChildWpfControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: could I have also a really border line (custom colored) around the childControl like this?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. you want your childWpfControl inside a border inside a scrollViewer?

Comment: the question is linked with this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197528/put-a-border-on-the-grid-in-wpf