# Put a border on the grid in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, border

Is there a way to put a `Border` on the `Grid` without surrounding the `Grid` with the `Border` element?

```
<Border Margin="{Binding ElementName=thisUserControl, Path=PrintMargin}"
        BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=thisUserControl, 
                             Path=PrintMarginThickness}"
        BorderBrush="LightGray">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid"
          Background="{Binding ElementName=thisUserControl, Path=Background}" />
</Border>
```

Could I use something like "BitmapEffect" on the grid or stuff like this?
I just need to display or not a border named "PrintMargin" on my WpfUserControl...

This border should or not be visible and also perhaps I need to control its **Thickness** and maybe **Color**(Brush)...

Comment: Why can't you use the `Border` element?  This is what it's *for*...

Comment: What is your motivation for not using it the way it is intended to be used?

Comment: I need that the grid parent be the usercontrol itself.

Comment: Why do you need the Grid parent to be the UserControl?

Comment: I have some elements on the grid, and need to identify the main grid, the grid that is different, whose Parent is the UserControl itself. Only that grid should have a special border

Comment: In that case, maybe you can name this grid and reference it by its name rather then position in the UI three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see anything wrong with doing the way you mentioned (border around the grid), but if you really want you can add `Border` as a last element in your `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    .. other elements ..
    <Border BorderBrush="DeepPink" BorderThickness="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you really, really want to do this (and I would urge strongly against it), make it the first element in the grid.  Otherwise, it could potentially overlap those other elements.  This way, the other elements overlap this one.  Of course, any overlap is really counter-intuitive to the idea of using a border in the first place.

Comment: I don't need a FIRST element, I need a border AROUND the grid itself

Comment: @serhio - Exactly. Put a Border Around the grid. `<Border><Grid /></Border>`

Comment: I need grid to be first UserControl child

Comment: @serhio You're trying to use the wrong tool for the job. Use the border control as it was designed to be and change the code that looks for the root grid to (ideally) refer to a **named** grid or, if you have to, walk the tree until it finds the first grid. Hacking a border without a `<border>` will only cause you problems later

Answer (score 1):

Well I did this for a `Button` a few weeks ago, maybe you can adapt the sample to the `Grid` control?

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

**EDIT:** I guess you'll have to use the `Panel` approach instead of the `ContentPresenter`, not sure how to do it from there, but hopefully this is somewhat helpful.